# Setting title in main activity

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I'm embarassed to post this question, but I'm trying for two hours to change title in my application's main activity and to, my surprise, no results. I tried:
`setTitle();`
`getActionBar().setTitle()` 
`getSupportActionBar().setTitle();`

Everyone is writing about those above, but none of them works. Even more surprisingly - in the other activities and fragments it's all fine. Only in this one.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_beer);

    Utils.checkGpsStatus(this);
    Utils.checkNetworkStatus(this);

    Location location = SmartLocation.with(this).location().getLastLocation();
    if(location != null){
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
    }

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_activity_beer);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }
    //viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainBeerActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_activity_beer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your activity code and also your layout xml file?

Comment: Please post the class in which you are having this error.

Comment: @MohammedAtif updated with code

Comment: And please don't downvote - it looks like an IDE error because there is no way `setTitle();` couldn't work.

Comment: Can you add your XML file too.

Comment: Try to Clean your project and then rebuild it

Comment: Are you extending Activity or AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @MohammedAtif updated!

Comment: @Eenvincible rebuilding project worked! Man, that was frustrating - thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">insert here title</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I want to change it programatically

Comment: Thats the default code which Android Studio does it without our intervention. Here he wants to set the title programatically.

Comment: my bad sorry, getSupportActionBar().setTitle("name here"); should work though, but you said it doesn't

Comment: it doesn't, surprisingly

Comment: do you have this in your onCreate() ?
that way you have to insert it in each activity to set the title

Comment: Eenvicible pointed the right way - I needed to rebuild project. Strange, but it worked - thanks for help :)

Comment: Do you want me to make it an answer so you can accept or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Extend your activity with extends AppCompatActivity.

Put below code in your onCreate method.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

This is the best practice to make your code compatible with latest devices because default actionbar is deprecated from Lollipop.